# what is the syntax for a negative case statement in elm?

Tags: pattern-matching, elm

I need to know how to do something like this in ELM.

```
case form.mode of
     "" ->  modeDropdown form

     (not "solo") -> do something for all other possibilities
```

Is this even possible?

**EDIT:**

To give broader context, I am trying to create cascading down-down lists. If I receive "" for mode in the url parameters, I need to show the first drop-down list. If I get "solo", I do not need to show anything. If I get any of the other choices besides "solo", I have to display the second drop-down list. It occurred to me that I can return an empty span tag for "solo" but that feels a little hacky.

Comment: The Haskell syntax would be `s | s /= "solo" -> do stuff`. Does Elm have anything like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this even possible?

The way it described in the question - no, because a pattern need to be provided in a `case` expression, not a boolean condition. But it can be performed the following way:

```
case form.mode of
    "" ->  modeDropdown form
    "solo" ->
        -- do something for `"solo"` possibility
     _ ->
        -- do something for all other possibilities
```

This way you provide `exhaustive pattern matching`, i. e. all the cases are considered.

Regarding the questions in the comment section:

> The Haskell syntax would be s | s /= "solo" -> do stuff. Does Elm have anything like that?

There is no syntax for functions with guards in Elm, so you need to imitate this behaviour using `if` conditions. Or there is [elm-guards](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Fresheyeball/elm-guards/latest) library, which makes it less verbose.

Comment: This is great, but how do I ignore the "solo" case? If that case is matched, I don't need to do anything. I'm sorry, I know this is rudimentary, but I am very new to Elm.

Comment: could you provide the example of the function, where this case expression is used? or at least types in order to see, what is the return type of the function

Comment: I mean, I Elm, you can't just ignore the case, you need to provide the value, which will fit the return type. For example, if it the `update` function, which return-type is (Model, Cmd msg), for `solo` case, you can just return non-modified model and Cmd.none

Comment: I gave a further explanation of what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks.

Comment: so, in your case, empty span or empty `Html.text ""` is the right way to go, since you need to return something to fit the types

Comment: I have to say, the ELM community is the most responsive and helpful of any tech I've worked with. Thanks very, very much.